# validate a string and make sure that it consists of specific characters

Tags: linux, unix

trying to validate a string at command line. each character should be among A-Z, a-z, 0-9 , special char(comma, underscore, period).   If there are any other characters, display "invalid" else valid"

eg:

```
echo "hello123.txt"    returns "valid"
echo "hello?.txt"  returns "invalid"
echo "HEllo_hello"  returns "valid"
```

Thank you.

Comment: That's not how `echo` works unfortunately. Maybe you can update with the code you have written already?

Comment: You can use a regular expression in `if`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a suitable version of grep, you can use `grep -v` to determine this:

```
echo "test" | grep -v "^[A-Za-z0-9,_.]*$" > /dev/null
echo $? # 1
echo "@test" | grep -v "^[A-Za-z0-9,_.]*$" > /dev/null
echo $? # 0
```

Comment: Why do you need a suitable version? AFAIK, the `-v` option has always been there.

Comment: Why don't you just invert the character class? `grep "[^A-Za-z...]"`?

Comment: Use `grep -q` (quiet) to avoid all of that redirection to `/dev/null`

Comment: Use `grep -i` so you only have to write `"^[a-z0-9,_.]*$"`

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can use pattern matching on the right hand side of the == operator in `[[ ... ]]`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for string in 'hello123.txt' 'hello?.txt' 'HEllo_hello' ; do
    if [[ $string == +([A-Za-z0-9,_.]) ]] ; then
        echo valid
    else
        echo invalid
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 = "" ]] ; then
  echo "Please run the following command with a string at the end...\
        Example= ./script.bash testing"
  exit 2
echo "$1" | grep -qi "^[a-z0-9.,_]*$"
if [[ $? = "0" ]] ; then
  echo "Valid"
else
  echo "Invalid"
fi
exit 0
```